# setGeometry() right after addWidget() issue

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm having troubles setting dimensions of a child-QWidget right after it is  added to a parent-QWidget.
The issue is that it simply doesn't set the geometry:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        # setting up parent QWidget
        self.setMinimumSize(256, 256)
        self.setMaximumSize(256, 256)
        self.GL = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.GL.setMargin(0)

        # setting up child QWidget
        self.GL.myWidget2 = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.GL.myWidget2.setMinimumSize(128, 128)
        self.GL.myWidget2.setMaximumSize(128, 128)
        self.GL.myWidget2.setStyleSheet("background: orange")

        # attaching child to parent
        self.GL.addWidget(self.GL.myWidget2)

        # trying to reposition child in parent's local space
        self.GL.myWidget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 128, self.width(), self.height()))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Adding a timer that sets the geometry after a short delay does work though... (replacing `self.GL.myWidget2.setGeometry([...])` with):

```
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.singleShot(10, self.updatePosition)

    def updatePosition(self):

        self.GL.myWidget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 128, self.width(), self.height()))
```

...so I suspect the addWidget(...) method to be doing a callback e.g. that redraws the widget in its default position while the main thread has already passed the `self.GL.myWidget2.setGeometry([...])` line.

This is purely speculative though, any inside into how `addWidget()` affects following coder or execution timing would be much appreciated!

Comment: Layouts manage the positioning of widgets. Normally, you don't put widgets into layouts _and_ position them manually. What are you trying to do? Perhaps you want `alignment/setAlignment` of `QLayout`?

Comment: why `self.GL.myWidget2` instead of `self.myWidget2`?

Comment: My apologies for a late response.
@Avaris: I hadn't been aware that widgets can be directly parented to other widgets and was under the impression that a layout is always required. My aim was to achieve exactly what the answer below examplifies.
X.Jacobs: This was meant for clarity reasons to keep a relational hierarchy. Adding the widget directly as a child to another widget was exactly what I intended - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to position your widget manually, there is no need for a layout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class orange(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(orange, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(256, 256)
        self.setMaximumSize(256, 256)

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(128, 128)
        self.frame.setMaximumSize(128, 128)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QRect(0, 128, self.width(), self.height()))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background: orange")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = orange()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```